# How to dynamically check all the checkboxes on a lightning-checkbox-group

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-checkbox-group

I am trying to use a lightning-input checkbox to check/uncheck all the options on a lightning-checkbox-group but the querySelector keeps returning no values.
This is the **HTML**:

```
<lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Select all" onchange={checkAllCheckboxes}></lightning-input>
                                <lightning-checkbox-group name="Checkbox Group"
                                        data-id="myChk"
                                        label="Select which schools to roll down"
                                        options={options}
                                        value={selectedValue}
                                        onchange={handleChange}>
                                </lightning-checkbox-group>
```

And this is the **JS**

```
checkAllCheckboxes(event){
        
        var checkboxGroup = this.template.querySelector('lightning-checkbox-group');
        var checkboxes = checkboxGroup.querySelectorAll('input');
        //var checkboxes = checkboxGroup.querySelectorAll('.slds-checkbox');
        console.log('checkboxes size:'+checkboxes.length);
        for (let ch of checkboxes){
            if (ch.type == 'checkbox'){
                console.log('type is checkbox');
                ch.checked = event.detail.checked;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the internal components of a component, because of the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom).

Instead, just set the `value` of the checkbox group to the desired values, specified as an Array of values.

```
this.selectedValue = this.options.map(
  (option) => option.value
);
```

To uncheck all the boxes, use an empty array.

```
this.selectedValue = [];
```